# Manual task in Jenkins to operate on selected run of selected job

Tags: deployment, jenkins, continuous-integration

Currently I have [batch task](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Batch+Task+Plugin) on each job that uploads the latest results to a server. It is our custom server and the upload is done by special script; standard upload tools won't cut it. The upload is not done for all builds, only manually when the build looks good.

This solutions is however not satisfactory for three reasons:

1. The batch task can only operate on the latest build. Sometimes I'd need to queue several builds and check and upload them to server afterwards.
2. The batch task needs to be replicated for several job. It is always the same except for parameter.
3. The batch task still requires a free executor, so it sometimes waits in a queue for completely different job.

I also considered creating a separate job with run parameter, but while this can be run on older results, but only run from a single job can be selected and it would complicate the user interface as it's not associated with the source job in any way.

Is there anything (via some plugin, perhaps) that could either be associated with job, but able to work on older artefacts, or be able to work on any artefacts of any job? (the third point is really separate question of how to provide a separate executor for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the "[Promoted Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin)" it can promote builds when certain conditions apply (like a successful downstream job). However, you can also promote the build manually. You can configure actions when a promotion occurs, like triggering a build of you upload job.